# How to set a button to search in database in Android ?

Tags: php, android, database, search, button

I have searched for so long. I just found that there are so many tutorials regarding connecting to DB , retrieving data using PHP and then pass the data to Android app and show ALL the data as a listview... But, there are so little info which teaching how to filter the data and just show the wanted data instead of ALL. For example, I type "XXX" in the edit text box , and press a "search" button , and the result only shows the data related to XXX.

I successfully connect the database using php to grep all the data in the table of my DB, now I'm thinking of how to use the data grep from php and display it as listview in android app based on the search requirement typed by the users.

What can I do next ? Please help and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I want to filter your data that you receive from database, so you can filter the whole list, performing the list and filtering the correct items. But I think the best approach is select the correct data from the database, thus you may create and execute a query. The following example is filtering contacs older than 18 years older and ordering by name. This simple example is using using SQLiteOpenerHelper, check this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html.

```
public List<Contact> findContactsByAge() {
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String query = "SELECT * FROM contact c " 
    " WHERE c.age > 18 AND "    
    " ORDER BY c.name";
    final Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setName(cursor.getString(0));
        contact.setAge(cursor.getString(1));
        contacts.add(contact);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return contacts;
}
```

I hope my explanation helps you, see you!

Answer (score 0):

I implemented custom search on sample data in simple listview. You can implement this logic with custom listview with custom adapter also. You can put all contacts result from above method in arralist variable bellow in the code.No need to make extra click by putting a separate button.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.examplesearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        final EditText search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        final ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraylist.add("Balvier");
        arraylist.add("Sudhier");
        arraylist.add("Abhinay");
        arraylist.add("Amit");
        arraylist.add("Dilip");
        final ArrayList<String> newArraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arraylist);

        newArraylist.clear();

        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                newArraylist.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                    if (search.getText().length() <= arraylist.get(i).length()) {
                        if (search
                                .getText()
                                .toString()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                        (String) arraylist.get(i).subSequence(
                                                0, search.getText().length()))) {
                            newArraylist.add(arraylist.get(i).toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                        newArraylist);
                list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.examplesearch.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/search"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hello Balvir Jha, thank you for your help ! I just tried your code. But it seems that it is a arraylist storing data instead of displaying data from MySql database ?

Comment: @CalvinNg You can fetch data from database and store that in arraylist. First you create a class depends what are your column names in tha table from which you are fetching the data. make an arraylist of that class type. you will have to create custom adapter. If you want more help, let me know.